# Probability of an ant going from one point to another on a lattice.

Tags: probability, puzzle, independence

I found this problem on brilliant.org. I get this kind of doubt a lot, in similar problems.
(This is my 1st question here, please go easy on me)

An ant stands on point A of the lattice below.

[This is the lattice image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctSrD.png)

Every minute, the ant selects an adjacent point uniformly at random and moves to it. For example, if the ant is on point B, then it moves to the points A, C, or G with probability **1/3**​ each.

What is the probability that the insect moves to point **D in exactly 2** moves from the point shown?

1. If I find the **product** of probabilities (A->G->D), the answer I get is **1/3*1/6 = 1/18**
2. But if I try to **count** the events, I get the probability to go from A to D in 2 steps as **1/12** (successful events/total events)

the 12 events being:

{A->B->C , A ->B->G, A->B->A , A ->F->E, A->F->A , A ->F->G, A->G->C , A ->G->A, A->G->B , A ->G->E, A->G->F , A ->G->D, }

The 1st answer is correct, but how? What are these 18 possible paths?

Comment: You can't count "total paths" here. The ant could go , for instance $A-B-A-B-A-G-A...$

Comment: The paths are not equally likely. The fact that there is one path with probability $1\over18$ doesn’t mean there need to be $18$ paths.

Comment: exemplifying @SteveKass 's point, imagine you have a biased coin that gives heads $1/3$rd of the time. This doesn't mean that there are $3$ possible outcomes on a coin toss. There are only 2 outcomes possible, heads with $1/3$ probability and tails with $2/3$ probability.

Comment: thanks for the clarification guys, but @true_blue_anil, I don't really get what you mean by the ant could go A-B-A-B-A-G-A... I now understand that all paths don't have the same probability, but for this question only the ant's first 2 steps are important? Why does it matter where it goes afterwards?

Comment: The q asks for the probability that the ant moves from A to D in **exactly** two steps, it does not preclude its moving there in more than $2$ steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix your $4$th event from $A \rightarrow F \rightarrow D$ to $A \rightarrow F \rightarrow E$ obviously.

That said, your $12$ events do not have the same probability. The first $6$ on the list have probability $1/9$, the other $6$ have probability $1/18$, because they pass by $G$. You want the probability of the last event $A \rightarrow G \rightarrow D$, which can be expressed as:

$$\frac{1}{18}=\frac{\frac{1}{18}}{6\frac{1}{9}+6\frac{1}{18}} \neq \frac{1}{6+6} = \frac{1}{12}$$